# Storing Solr indexes on a NFS mount

Tags: filesystems, solr, network-storage, lucene, network-filesystem

Are there are any performance considerations / drawbacks of storing Solr index files on a NFS mount?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. I have some Lucene indexes persisting onto NFS and it works very well. Haven't had any issues with it.